# Use defined value in module provider in other Angular module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-module, angular-providers

I would like use provider value defined in other module. Here is example:

**app.module.ts**

```
...

import { ThemeModule } from '../shared/modules/theme/theme.module';

...

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    RootComponent,
    LoginScreenComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ConfigModule,
    ThemeModule,
    ....
  ],

  providers: [
    ...
    { provider: "THEME_NAME", useValue: "VALUE" },
  ],
 
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class MDMToolModule {}
```

**theme.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ThemeService } from './services/ThemeService';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        {provide: "ThemeService", useFactory: (THEME_NAME) => {
            return new ThemeService(THEME_NAME)
        }},
    ],
    exports: []
})
export class ThemeModule {}
```

Is there possibility to pass VALUE defied not in module like above example (*THEME NAME*)?

Answer (score 0):

if you're providing value in root module then it will be available to all other modules too so you can then simply ask for that value using Inject decorator like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
  constructor(@Inject("THEME_NAME") theme: string) {}
}
```

otherwise you can import your `MDMToolModule` inside `ThemeModule` though judging by the code you provided I'm assuming this `MDMToolModule` is your root module,
you can also use Injection Token to avoid using those magic strings like this:

```js
const ThemeName = new InjectionToken("token to inject theme name");
```

and then use it inside **theme.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: ThemeName, useValue: "DarkKnight" },
    ThemeService
  ]
})
export class ThemeModule {}
```

**theme.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThemeService {
  constructor(@Inject(ThemeName) theme: string) {}
}
```

Comment: woops just realized, I provided `ThemeName` in `ThemeModule` but you can provide it in your root module or some other module(in this case, import that module in `ThemeModule`)